# How to create ranges in R and if the numbers in a column of my dataframe matches the interval, we can create a new column labeled by 1

Tags: r

Say I have a column of values in my data frame that consists of

[1.0,1.01,1.1,2.01,2.1]

I want to create an interval for example [1.0,1.1) inclusive,non-inclusive
I also have a column vector filled with 0's that have the same number of numbers as my column of values.

If the col of values matches the interval, we change the interval number from 0 to 1.

What is the easiest way to do this in R? And also how can I automate this for a larger column of values?

(Creating multiple intervals such as [1.0,1.1) + [1.1,1.2) + [1.2,1.3) + etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cut` to create the bins by specifying the `breaks`  and then `split` by the bins created to a `list` of `vector`s

```
grp <- cut(df1$col, breaks = c(-Inf, seq(1.0, 2.0, by = 0.1), Inf))
lst1 <- split(df1$col, grp)
```

Comment: Can I pull out all the values of each interval? What I want to do is average the values in each interval and replace those numbers with the average.

Comment: @chris  Yes, you can `split` by the 'bins into a `list` and then pull out the `list` elements with `lst1[[1]]` or the value of the bins

Comment: So after pulling the values and computing the average how can one put the average into all the values in the interval?

Comment: @chris  For that you can just use `ave` i.e. `ave(df1$col, grp)`